# Symfony 2 not rendering Welcome Page as expected

Tags: php, css, symfony, rendering

after using Zend Framework 2 for a while, I decided to try out Symfony 2 yesterday. Installation on my Debian Jessie test server went smooth and after commenting out the localhost restrictions in config.php (and also app_dev.php of course) I was able to complete the basic configuration steps (even though I had already taken care of it in the according yaml file previously). 
After loading the welcome page, I was pretty surprised when I found out that it heavily differed from what the documentation made me expect.

Unfortunately all I'm seeing is the word "Homepage." and the toolbar along the bottom of the window.

I spent a lot of time searching the web and found a hand full of topics that reflected my experience. None of these were answered though. I found a couple of similar issues, but none of the provided solutions worked for me. My Apache Vhost config is absolutely fine (pointing to the web folder for example) and so is my PHP configuration. I have done zero coding in the Symfony project so far, so it can't have been me who caused the issue. ;) Seriously though, I'm really completely clueless as to what might probably be causing the page to render incorrectly. I can see that there's not a single CSS file loaded in the head part of the source code, which leads me to believe that there's no bootstrapping taking place. But since I have not the slightest experience with Symfony 2, this is just me guessing.
Btw, I double checked, the Acme DemoBundkle is installed. Someone somewhere mentioned that the Welcome Page in the documentation was showing exactly that.

If you guys have any idea, please enlighten me, as I would really like to give Symfony 2 a shot.

[Edit]

I've been digging a little deeper into it this morning, and despite the routing being correct and parsed, he app/Resources/views/default is loaded, where it should load src/Acme/DemoBundle/views/Welcome/index.html.twig

I'm getting closer to the solution. I'll update this post as soon as I resolved the issue.

Comment: How did you installed it ? If was by composer, did composer finished his job ?
If it was this, just tell, and I will answer your question. Need to know some clues first, otherwise will be a shot in the dark :)

Comment: I used the executable logic: symfony new <project name>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure that this can be considered best practice, but at least I was able to resolve the issue. Symfony was always loading the DefaultController, which indexAction method renders the default/index.html.twig template:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    Homepage.
{% endblock %}
```

Since I wasn't able to find any other way to make the AcmeDemo Welcome page the default page to load, I changed

```
* @Route("/", name="homepage"
```

to

```
* @Route("/default", name="homepage"
```

in *src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php*

I'm almost certain that there has to be a way to configure any other page to be displayed as default without having to change the defaultController, but I have yet to figure out how.

[Edit]

Alright, got it. I reverted the changes I made to the *DefaultController* and improved the *WelcomeController*:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
.
.
.
class WelcomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="_welcome")
     .
     .
     .
}
```

and accordingly in *src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml*:

```
_welcome:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/WelcomeController.php"
    type:     annotation
```

Now it's working perfectly fine without any changes to the DefaultController, which was - I believe - far from being best practice, as it's likely a core file.

Like I said, I'm completely new to Symfony 2 and it differs a lot from Zend Framework (for good though!), so what may appear as basic knowledge to you, didn't for me. :)

Answer (score 3):

My best guess would be to execute via command line:

```
app/console cache:clear

app/console assets:install --env=dev

app/console assetic:dump --env=dev
```

Considering you are entering in the development app_dev.php front end controller. 
That will build your CSS assets. Try it out.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it, but it didn't change a thing. :/ Neither app.php nor app_dev.php changed. This is really bugging the hell out of me.

Comment: Then it must be something with your virtual host configuration. Check that you have it correctly set up: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html

Comment: It's a very simple and basic configuration. I highly doubt that this is the culprit here, seriously. :(

Comment: Have you checked the PHP logs ? Enabled the PHP display_errors or check the logs to see if the code is having an error somewhere because of your configuration.
And have you checked permissions ? ( app/log and app/cache should be writable)

Comment: Logs are empty. And yes, Display_errors is enabled, displaying E_ALL. Stil, not a single error is displayed. Permissions for Cache and logs are fine.

Answer (score 0):

i've also experienced the exact same problem as you. It seems that the developer that created the project generator forgot to setup the routing.yml before deploying their apps.

to fix this, just simply change the `app/config/routing.yml`

from

```
resource: @AppBundle/Controller/
```

to

```
resource: @AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/
```

it only change the default controller to call on the homepage, nothing possibly endanger the integrity of your symfony project.

I've only just now found this, since i'm relearning symfony (the last time i used it, it was still on 1.4)

Cheers!

Comment: @TimOgilvy sadly, this time they removed the acmedemobundle entirely.

you could only access localhost:8000/app/example to access the default homepage. it will even give you error 404 not found if you try to access only localhost:8000/

Comment: I guess since Symfony is not actually an application on its own, it does somewhat make sense for it to be empty and fail 'out of the box'...  but they haven't updated the doc to reflect that. I should probably try to find the github page or something to send them some feedback

Comment: @TimOgilvy yeah, but it's still nice to see some kind of basic implementation of some functions to give the new developer a sense for how to use some of the framework's basic function. Or they could also use an additional param to the symfony new command to use whether the example project or a completely empty project

Answer (score 0):

1. change routing path
2. work in incognito mode